# Best way to uniquely identify a type

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

This seems like a simple question on its surface but I thought I'd reach out to the community for this one. I am serializing .NET types in a stream and need some way to uniquely identify each type so that I know how to deserialize the type on the other side. I've thought of various approaches:

1. Annotate each type with an attribute that requires an integer to identify the message type
2. Do the same as #1 except use a GUID
3. Hashing the fully qualified name

I would love to be able to do this without requiring the attribute. Using an integer is conflict prone. Generating GUIDs every time I create a new type is cumbersome. The third option seems possible but also has the possibility of conflicts, albeit somewhat isolated.

What I'd like to be able to do is infer this uniqueness in a deterministic way so that any object can be passed in and deserialized on the other end without having to mark it up somehow. Assume that I already have a way to register all known types on both ends, so before any message is sent, both ends already have a list of acceptable types. All I'd like to do is make the process of registering those known types less clunky.

Edit: I'd like to be as small on the wire as possible while still achieving the uniqueness I require.

Comment: Why not use the **fully-qualified type name** ?? That ought to be unique enough ....

Comment: What about the same type in different versions of assembly? Would you like to identify them as the same type or two different types?

Comment: I'd prefer to treat like-named types in different assemblies as different. Maybe not, though ...

Comment: @JohnHargrove but tomp's question is about like-named types in different versions of the *same* assembly.

Comment: Right, sorry. (I am super out of it today). That is an important consideration. I would prefer that it not be based on the version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Type.GUID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.guid.aspx) for example...

IF that does not fit your case please provide more details...

Comment: That's the same as option #2 ... it requires you to annotate the class with `GuidAttribute` type. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx)

Comment: @JohnHargrove from the link you provided: *Supplies an explicit System.Guid when an automatic GUID is undesirable.* which means it works without an attribute BUT whether this would be fine for your case depends on several aspects you did not provide...

Comment: Aha, you are correct. Interesting. It remains the same through rebuilds as well. I wonder how this magic works ... ?

Comment: Appears to be based on the name of the type.

Comment: @JohnHargrove but there are more possible names of types than there are GUIDs, so, with enough types, you're guaranteed to have collisions.  Therefore, even with fewer types, there's a small chance of it.

Comment: This best fits the requirements in my question.

Comment: @JohnHargrove I agree that this answer is the best fit for your question.  I'm just saying that I wouldn't do this in a production environment unless I could be certain that there would be no collisions.

Comment: @phoog: "with enough types, you're guaranteed to have collisions"... Guids are 128 bit numbers. That's 3*10^38 possible Guids. If the name hashing works well, that's going to be a huge # of types before collision might become a real hazard.

Comment: @spender something can be a real hazard even if the chance of its happening is very small.  Obviously, nobody's going to have enough types to guarantee a collision.  My point is that the *chance* of a collision is there.  If the cost of a collision is "we catch it in testing and it adds a couple of days to our development time", great, let's use the GUID approach.  If the cost of a collision is "our site goes down for 2 weeks and we lose millions of dollars of revenue" then, no, I'm not going to use the GUID approach.  It *probably won't* happen, but it could.

Comment: 128 Bit is more than the quantity of atoms in our universe - while this in theory still not absolutely collision-proof it is rather safe IMHO. I recommend to always have some testing code when implementing such mechanisms - for example as a guard against someone "spoofing a GUID (i.e. taking an already assigned GUID and attaching it explicitely as an attribute to a different type).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answers available I would suggest to use fully quaified type name. It already guarantees uniquness inside your application domain.

Comment: That seems like the direction to go ... I guess one thing I didn't mention above is that I need to be as small on the wire as possible, which is why I mentioned hashing the fully qualified type name ... Hmm.

Comment: There is another thing to consider too. What if you have 2 assemblies with different *versions*? In this way they will result like a different types. If you don't want that, you can generate your unique type string, base on that one provided by framework itself, but without version information.

Comment: Aha, you are correct. Interesting. It remains the same through rebuilds as well. I wonder how this magic works ... ?

Comment: Posted the above comment to the wrong answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Good point about the version ... that's a very important consideration.

Comment: @JohnHargrove It's not generally possible to calculate a unique hash for every fully-qualified type name.  You'd have to do some kind of specialized approach, like a lookup table.